# Getting a UICollectionViewCell before the first cell is loaded in the UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using an API that allows me to specify the dimensions of the images I fetch. In order to maximize network efficiency, I'm attempting to make the requested dimension exactly match the dimensions of the image view within a collection view cell.

The issue here is that in order to specify the correct dimensions in the API request, I need to first know the dimension of the image view frame. BUT - no cells are loaded into the view UNTIL the API request has been completed. A classic chicken and the egg ordeal.

The question is how do I get the dimensions of a UIImageView inside a UICollectionViewCell from a UICollectionView that has not yet loaded any cells. Make sense?

My first and only hope, which failed, was the following:

```
let cell = self.topSellersCollectionView.visibleCells.first as! HomeProductsCell
```

I was thinking that maybe swift loaded an "empty template" cell initially even if the data had not yet been set. This is obviously not the case.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know frame of the imageView by

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
      super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
      self.collectionView.frame.size.width // Also subtract cell spacing to get correct dimension 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As your answer suggests, with a lot of math, I could deduce the collection view dimensions, then deduce the cell dimensions, then deduce the image view dimensions - but this would have to be modified for every type of cell I use. Is there a way to actually grab the dimensions of the image view without having to "math it out"?

Comment: To clarify, I'm looking for a method to "cast" the cell that has not yet been loaded into a variable to get the exact frame dimensions. It might not be possible.

Comment: You can wait until **collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:** and get the dimension but for only that cell (only visibleCells are loaded) but the request will be delayed until that plus showing dummy image and i recommended answer approach as it's earlier and will enable you fetch the request fastly with no dummy image if the connection is good

Comment: Roger that. Close enough is close enough.